# Ordering row having same values in two columns on top

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data similar to one given below:

```
ID  UserID  PlayerID    Name
1   56      21          A
2   57      34          B
3   77      77          C
4   65      23          D
5   77      77          E
```

I want the rows with same value in UserID and PlayerID column to be at the top.

I have currently done this:

```
select * from tblTest 
order by abs(UserID - PlayerID ) asc
```

Any better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * From tblTest 
Order By Case When UserID = PlayerID Then 0 Else 1 End
```

Comment: In what way is it better? Is it better just because it avoids the negation operator or will this statement have better performance?